# Nuxt auth-module google login promise on success

Tags: javascript, vue.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt with the [auth-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module).

Logging in to Google works:

```
this.$auth.loginWith("google").then(() => {
    console.log("Logged in!");
});
```

Here is my google login strategy:

```
google: {
    scope: [
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata"
    ],
    client_id: "CLIENT_ID",
    response_type: "code",
    access_token_endpoint: "http://localhost:4000/auth/google/"
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that the promise is resolved as soon as the login button is clicked. So that "Logged in!" is written to the console. This is not expected behavior. The promise should be resolved when the user returns from a successful OAuth2 flow.

Does someone know what's wrong?

Comment: Does it happen when running in a new incognito window? If not, it's most likely you're non-incognito window is storing an already authenticated token (as a cookie most likely) and preventing the request from happening.

Comment: I have faced the same situation. Have you solved the question? If yes, could you give me a hint?

Comment: i have same question